# What taxes do I pay on interest earned on a savings or GIC account?

Tags: taxes, canada, savings-account

If I put 10 000 $ in a savings account that pays 1% interest, then after a year, I get 100 dollars in interest. Is this 100 $ taxed at my marginal tax rate? 
Does the answer change if the account was a GIC instead of a savings account?
Of course both the GIC and the savings account are non tax sheltered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interest income is [taxed at your marginal income tax rate](http://www.bmonesbittburns.com/IA/IAHomepage/NewsToBrowser.asp?IA_ID=PDELIA&LANGUAGE=EN&NEWS_ID=16&VERSION=null). Specifically,

> Investments such as Canada Savings Bonds, GIC’s, T-bills or strip bonds, pay interest income which is taxed at your marginal tax rate without any preferential tax treatment. For individuals, interest must be reported on your tax return in the year you receive it and at least annually on the anniversary day of the investment.

This is different from the [tax treatment of dividend income and other capital gains.](http://www.taxtips.ca/personaltax/investing/investmentincometaxrates.htm)